# Why do we only consider $x\to 1$ and not $x\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ for the solution to $\dot x=k(1-x)x$ with $x=x_0$ at $t=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

**Q.** Solve the differential equation $\dot{x}=k(1-x)x~,~k\gt 0$ with the initial value $x=x_0$ at $t=0$. Hence, show that $x\to 1$ as $t\to +\infty$

**Solution:**

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{x(1-x)}=k\,\mathrm dt$$

Integrating both sides and using partial fractions for the LHS, we get,

$$\ln|x(1-x)|=-kt+\color{gray}{\textrm{Constant}}$$

Using the given initial value and simplifying stuff, we get,

$$\ln\left|\frac{x(1-x)}{x_0(1-x_0)}\right|=-kt$$

As $t\to+\infty$, since $k\gt 0$, we have $-kt\to -\infty$ and hence, using the above,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln\left|\frac{x(1-x)}{x_0(1-x_0)}\right|=-\infty\implies \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{x(1-x)}{x_0(1-x_0)}=0\implies \lim_{t\to\infty} x(1-x)=0$$

The above implies that either $x\to 0$ or $x\to 1$ as $t\to\infty$.

---

My question is why/how do we exclude the $x\to 0$ case?

Comment: If $x$ is converging to zero, it must be decreasing for some $x$ near zero...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, $t$ is the independent variable and $x(t)$ is the function in $t$. Are you considering it the other way around? It seems so from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integration is incorrect, the derivative of $\ln|x(1-x)|$ is
$$
\frac{1-2x}{x(1-x)}
$$
and not your original integrand.

---

The correct method is to use partial fraction decomposition to get
$$
\frac1{x(1-x)}=\frac1x+\frac1{1-x}
$$
resulting in the anti-derivative
$$
\ln|x|-\ln|1-x|=\ln\left|\frac x{1-x}\right|
$$

---

In a more qualitative view notice that you can see from the differential equation that $\dot x$ is positive on $(0,1)$, zero at $0$ and $1$ and negative elsewhere, thus any solution starting in $(0,1)$ stays inside this interval and converges monotonically increasing towards $1$. Any solution starting in $(1,\infty)$ also stays inside that interval and converges monotonically decreasing towards $1$. However, starting inside $(-\infty,0)$ the solution is monotonically decreasing towards $-\infty$, so that for that half axis the original statement is wrong.

Comment: Which part of the original statement is wrong? $x$ does tend to $1$ as $t$ tends to positive infinity, right?

Comment: Only for $x_0>0$ which I do not see in the statement.